# Uniform identifier/class naming across HTML, CSS and JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

How does one ensure that HTML, CSS and JS have uniform identifiers. For example, one such set of identifiers could be class names. e.g.:

CSS:

```
.user-profile{
  ...
}
```

JS:

```
document.getElementsByClassName( "user-profile" ).(...)
```

HTML:

```
<div class="user-profile"> ... </div>
```

Are there any IDEs that can provide this functionality? Given that these are technically strings, I'd assume it would be hard to determine 'equality'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no variables in HTML. I think you are talking about `id` and `class` attributes.

When you change an `id` or a `class`, the easiest way to reflect the change in CSS and JavaScript is to `grep` the related files.

I'm not sure an automated renaming by an IDE would be helpful: there are many cases where you don't want CSS/JavaScript files to be modified. A basic example: you change a class of an element, because you want a different style.

Also, if you have to do *a lot* of changes in `id`s and `class`es, check that you're using proper naming conventions and you chose the values thoughtfully from the beginning.